# Confused about function closures

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, closures

Can someone please explain why does it console log out 10, 10, 10 instead of 9, 9, 9?
When it goes through for loop shouldn't it stop at 9?

```
var foo = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  foo[i] = function() {
    return i;
  };
};

console.log(foo[0]());
console.log(foo[1]());
console.log(foo[2]());
```

Comment: By the time foo is executed, `i` has already reached **10**, courtsey `i++`

Comment: `i++` is evaluated at the end of each loop. So, it **has to be 10** for the next loop not executing (since the condition is `i < 10`).

Comment: It seems that your main confusion is not with closures, but with how `for` loops work.

Comment: @JLRishe Indeed... yet, OP accepted an answer which doesn't explain the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever any `function` which is using any variable from parent scope is executed, it gets that value of a variable which it is holding at the time of `function` execution. In your case `i` is already reached to `10` at the time of execution because of `i++`.

For getting expected result, you can add `IIFE` to it, which will hold the value of `i` in its scope.

```js
var foo = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  foo[i] = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      return i;
    };
  })(i);
};

console.log(foo[0]());
console.log(foo[1]());
console.log(foo[2]());
```

Comment: OP's expected result was 9, 9, 9, so this doesn't produce their expected result.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this syntax which keeps the context

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  foo[i] = () =>  i;
};

console.log(foo[0]());
console.log(foo[1]());
console.log(foo[2]());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bandpay/8zat3bnn/